# Query to retrieve tags for video doesn't return propper value

Tags: php, mysql

I have page where I load 10 videos. Now I'm trying to show for each video what tags has. So I've loaded videos then I trying like this for the tags

```
$tags = $pdo->prepare("Select * From `video` p LEFT JOIN `tags_image` tp ON p.video_id = tp.video_id LEFT JOIN `tag` t ON tp.tags_id = t.tag_id WHERE p.video_id = ?");
$tags -> bindParam(1, $row['video_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$tags -> execute();
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if(!$tag){
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a href="tagsPreview.php?tag_id='.$tag['tag_id'].'">'.$tag['tag_name'].'</a></li>';  
    }
    else {
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a href="">No tags found for the video</a></li>';
    }                  
}
```

Tables in database are `video` - `video_id`,`video_name` ... etc

`tag` - `tag_id`, `tag_name`

`tags_image` - `tags_id`, `video_id`.

So when I open the page video with ID=1 has associated 5 tags but video get 5 times - `No tags found for the video` instead of 5 tags. What I miss here?

Comment: Remove `!` here: `if(!$tag){`

Comment: Yes, this is one way.. but then I don't have else statement.

Comment: I just tried and I've got empty space instead of `No tags found for the video`

Comment: That's because you aren't fetching your records. After `$tags->execute` add `$tags = $tags->fetchAll();`

Comment: Still same. If you check in else statement I have blank href. Now I have empty space which is href - `tagsPreview.php?tag_id=`. So for me this means that doesn't go into else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if($tag['tag_id']){
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a href="tagsPreview.php?tag_id='.$tag['tag_id'].'">'.$tag['tag_name'].'</a></li>'; 
    } else {
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a>Към видеото няма добавени тагове</a></li>';
    }                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with:

```
if(!empty($tag['tag_id'])){
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a href="tagsPreview.php?tag_id='.$tag['tag_id'].'">'.$tag['tag_name'].'</a></li>';  
    }
    else {
            echo '<li style="margin-top: -13px;"><a href="">No tags found for the video</a></li>';
    }
```

Comment: Then I don't get `else` when video doesn't have tags.. just empty space

Comment: Use this to check tag_id present or not

Comment: Now I get else block... before I got tags but video which doesn't have was emtpy block.

Comment: use two seperate queries 1) For video & 2) tag

Comment: They are like this. First I show all videos and this for tags is after the query for videos. That's how I get `video_id`.

Comment: first fetch video & by video id fetch data from tags.

Comment: Like I said this is what I do. First I have query to load videos, then is this query to load the tags.